# Edit text of html element based on result of PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I'm returning to PHP after a long break. I'm trying to have a page output a message depending on the result of a boolean. Right now, I have a single paragraph tag in the body of that page with the corresponding text. Something like this:

```
<html>
    <p class ="class">Contents</p>
<html>

<?php
    if(TRUE) {
        // make contents of paragraph read "true"
    }
    if(FALSE) {
        // make contents of paragraph read "false
    }
?>
```

I don't believe I can change the contents of the paragraph tag with CSS. Is there a simpler way to accomplish something like this short of creating two separate landing pages with different messages?

Comment: Put the `IF` inside the paragraph tag.  PHP can't change content that has already been outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While others are going to downvote and slam you because this is the absolute basics of PHP, here you go:

```
<?php
    if(true) {
        $var = "True";
    } else {
        $var = "False";
    }
?>

<html>
    <p class ="class"><?php echo $var; ?></p>
</html>
```

OR

```
<html>
    <p class ="class">
    <?php
        if(true) {
            echo "True";
        } else {
            echo "False";
        }
    ?>
    </p>
</html>
```

There are several other ways to accomplish this, that's the beauty of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $myBool = true; ?>

<h1>
   HELLO, <?php echo $myBool ? "WORLD" : "STRANGER"; ?>
</h1>
```

Similarly:

```
<?php $user = ""; ?>

<h1>
   HELLO, <?php echo empty($user) ? "STRANGER" : $user; ?>
</h1>
```